# Regex - how to capture text in quotes within parentheses

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am using http://www.rubular.com/ to test how much pattern matching will work. 
If I have text such as `AND TO_CHARCREATE_TS, 'yyyymmdd' = '20140810'` , the regex `AND TO_CHARCREATE_TS, yyyymmdd = '(.*?)'` allows me to extract the time stamp. However, when parenthesis are introduced such as `AND (TO_CHAR(CREATE_TS, 'yyyymmdd') = '20140810')`, I cannot get my regex `AND (TO_CHAR(CREATE_TS, 'yyyymmdd') = '(.*?)' )` to extract the time stamp. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written to perform this? I mean, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

If the Parenthesis are in the actual string you are trying to match, they need to be escaped with '\' for it to match.

```
AND \(TO_CHAR\(CREATE_TS, 'yyyymmdd'\) = '(.*?)'\)
```

Will match the example

```
AND (TO_CHAR(CREATE_TS, 'yyyymmdd') = '20140810')
```

Also, depending on what else is going on in the query that you are matching, you may be able to simplify the regex to grab just a quoted timestamp like this:

```
'(\d{8})'
```

Which will match any 8 digits inside of single-quotes